# Why codeigniter output class return empty an array when created dynamically

Tags: php, arrays, codeigniter, output

Im trying to fill an array dynamically this way:

```
    $columns = array();
    foreach ($this->get_selectors() as $value) {
    $element = array();
        $element['data']= $value;
        $columns[]= $element;
    }
```

the output $var_dump($columns) to this is:

```
  array(4) {
     [0]=>
       array(1) {
         ["data"]=>
             string(3) "one"
       }
     [1]=>
       array(1) {
         ["data"]=>
             string(3) "two"
       }
     [2]=>
       array(1) {
         ["data"]=>
             string(5) "three"
       }
     [3]=>
       array(1) {
         ["data"]=>
             string(4) "four"
       }
  }
```

But when i try to pass it through

```
    $this->output->set_content_type('application/json')
                                    ->set_output(json_encode($columns));
```

I get nothing.

Comment: I reproduce your data according to the value of your $columns and see if there any error on the output but nothings there.. thus this $this->get_selectors() always have data. if no data then you will really receive an empty result from $this->output->set_content_type('application/json')
                                    ->set_output(json_encode($columns));

Comment: i already figured out were the problem was, the thing is for some reason          $this->get_selectors() return empty when it actually is already been set, but anyways, thanks.